# Rankings out of integer and a half?

Tags: single-word-requests, mathematics

When giving items a score its not uncommon to restrict values to make scoring easier.

For example:

> I can give a movie a score out of 5 stars using only integers, i.e. 0,1,2,3,4,5. Or I can give a movie a ranking out of 5 using *integer and a halves*, e.g. 1 star, 1 and a half stars, (but I'd never give a score of 2 and a third).

Is there a proper term for *integer and a half*?

Comment: The term is half-integers:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-integer.

Answer (score 2):

If you allow half a star, you can use the term [**half-integer**](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20half%20integer&oq=define%20half%20integer):

> a number obtained by dividing an odd integer by two ( 1/2, 1 1/2, 2 1/2, etc.).